# markdown, can you insert image inbetween ordered list items?

Tags: markdown

Can you insert an image in between list items?

1. first
2. second

[image]
<sub>(source: [codekeyboards.com](http://codekeyboards.com/img/code-104-bright-backlit.jpg))</sub>

**figure 1** the new keyboard..wonder if it's good

3. third

The **third** is preceeded with `3.` actually, but shown as `1.`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you mean in html or SO-markup?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just indent the image and `**figure...**` stuff so that Markdown sees it as part of the bullet:

```
1. first
2. second

 ![](http://codekeyboards.com/img/code-104-bright-backlit.jpg)

 **figure 1** the new keyboard..wonder if it's good

3. third
```

Or in action:

---

1. first
2. second

   [image]

   **figure 1** the new keyboard..wonder if it's good
3. third

Comment: Markdown will automatically number the list. It is not needed to manually type 1. first 2. second... Instead type 1. first 1. second (note the repeated sequence of 1s)

Answer (score 21):

I needed to indent them by 4 spaces. [markdown manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/7/markdown)'s list section talks about this.

```
1. first
2. second

    ![](http://codekeyboards.com/img/code-104-bright-backlit.jpg)
    
    **figure 1** the new keyboard..wonder if it's good

3. third
```

Comment: This worked for me.  It was important to also include a full-line gap between the text of the bullet point and the image.

Comment: Indenting them with 4 spaces works for markdown used in Jekyll pages too.

Comment: This is the correct answer as it pertains to GitHub's Markdown.