# How to render images inside an ordered list in GitHub markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

I am having problems rendering an image that's placed inside an ordered list.

Currently, my code looks as follows:

```markdown
4. Element number four.

    a) ![image](link-to-public-image-in-google-drive)

    b) More text down here!!!

5. Element number five.
```

By doing this, the image appears as a hyperlink on the word "image" (and I want the image to be displayed, not hyperlinked).

I changed the code to this:

```markdown
4. Element number four.

    a)

![image](link-to-public-image-in-google-drive)

    b) More text down here!!!

5. Element number five.
```

and now the image is being displayed correctly. However, the text contained between the image and element number five is being rendered as a block of code (i.e., the text `"b) More text down here!!!"` is rendered as a block of code).

How can I display the image inside the list without messing up the formatting of the rest of the text?

Comment: Try to intent the image in the second code block.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525892/markdown-can-you-insert-image-inbetween-ordered-list-items).